# Alt-Tab Switch does not show Chrome Full-Screen window in Windows 10 - Bug?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

Probably a bug in Chrome or Windows 10?

1. Open Chrome, several instances at best.
2. Hide the bookmark bar with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd>.
3. Go to Fullscreen Mode in one Chrome window by hitting <kbd>F11</kbd>.
4. Switch between programs with <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd>.
5. You will notice that the Fullscreen window has disappeared from the programs.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Chrome and Windows 10 Version?

Comment: Chrome Version 59.0.3071.115, Windows Version 10.0.15063

Comment: then reset all the flags of Chrome. Use this URL Bar. `chrome://flags` You can see **Reset all to default** Button click and reset all the flags. This may help you.

Comment: @TechieGossip Just tried it with Win10 + Chrome 59.0.3 and window is visible in the square list

Comment: @Magnum what You Tried?

Comment: @TechieGossip I followed your steps to reproduce the issue you have.

Comment: Chrome just updated to the latest Version 60.0.3112.78. Now the problem disappeared. Question can be closed. Thanks.

Comment: Feel free to write up your answer and accept it.  In case anyone else may have this problem.

Comment: Update: When using Google Slides, going into Presentation Mode (which is Chrome in fullscreen), then using `Alt Tab` a couple of times (with releasing it), after some attempts, the fullscreen window does not show up anymore! So **bug still exists**.