# Chrome window don't show in the alt tab menu when chrome in fullscreen mode, it appears and diseapears randomly?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

when I was working with codepen, and because my screen is a bit small, I needed to enable the fullscreen mode to have more space, so I used the alt-tab key combination to switch to the other window of chrome, then when I want to return to the codepen window using the key combination I don't find chrome, when I keep trying and pressing the alt-tab key the window just shows randomly, any solve for it please?
chrome version: 75.0.3770.100 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: Stable)
Windows version: Windows 10 OS Version 1809 (Build 17763.557)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alt-Tab Switch does not show Chrome Full-Screen window in Windows 10 - Bug?](https://superuser.com/questions/1236809/alt-tab-switch-does-not-show-chrome-full-screen-window-in-windows-10-bug)

Comment: I saw it, the given solve there is to update chrome while I tried that and it's updated.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll take that back. Could you specify the version of Chrome you're using (by editing your question), to avoid further misunderstandings?

Comment: Unfortunately no, and though I switched from chrome to opera, I'm still facing the same issue, probably the problem is from windows.

Answer (score 0):

It's still happening. The solution is to enable **Hardware acceleration** in the settings.

I turned it off when was running GPU-saturated tasks, to prevent videos from buffering. Then started encountering this issue and luckily remembered to check this exact setting. Can be reliably reproduced.